# Memory leaks despite destructor call

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, memory-leaks

I'm working on a class LinkedList which looks like this:

```
private:
    LL_element* first;
    LL_element* last; 
    int size;
public:
    //constructor
    Linkedlist(): first(NULL), last(NULL), size(0) {}

    //destructor
    ~Linkedlist();

    //adds element at the end of the list.
    void push_back(int value);

    //removes an element at the end of the list.
    bool pop_back(int& value);
```

The function push_back creates a new LL_element object (dynamically allocated).
The function pop_back explicitly deletes the element at the end of the list.
The destructor uses the function pop_back as long as the list is not empty. 
The problem is that when I create a Linkedlist object:

```
Linkedlist foo =   Linkedlist();
foo.push_back(3);
foo.push_back(5);
```

When foo goes out of scope the destructor is called, but Visualstudio still gives me memoryleaks of the LL_elements. However when I dynamically allocate:

```
Linkedlist* foo = new Linkedlist();
foo->push_back(3);
foo->push_back(5);
```

And then call the destructor with 'delete', VS does not give memoryleaks.

Is the destructor not properly called by the compiler or is the default constructor not properly used when creating a Linkedlist on the stack? It's really
confusing me...

The code for push_back and pop_back:

```
bool Linkedlist:: pop_back(int& value) {

//only if the list is not empty, an element can be removed.
if(!this->is_empty()) {

    value = this->last->get_value();
    LL_element* removed = this->last;
    this->last = removed->get_previous();

    if(this->size!=1) {
    this->last->set_next(NULL);
    }

    delete removed; 
    size--;
    return true;
}   

value = 0;
cout << EMPTY_LIST_MESSAGE << endl;
return false;}

void Linkedlist:: push_back(int value)
{

LL_element* to_add = new LL_element(value);

//if there already is a first element, we can ignore it
if(!this->is_empty()) {

    this->last->set_next(to_add);
    to_add->set_previous(last);
    this->last = to_add;
    size++;

}

//if the list is empty --> special case.
else {

    this->first = to_add;
    this->last = to_add;
    size++;

}
}
```

An SSCCE:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

Linkedlist foo; 
foo.push_back(3);
foo.push_back(5);
foo.push_back(6);
foo.push_back(7); 
_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{139} normal block at 0x00A58148, 12 bytes long.
 Data: <            > 00 00 00 00 00 81 A5 00 07 00 00 00 
{138} normal block at 0x00A58100, 12 bytes long.
 Data: <H           > 48 81 A5 00 B8 80 A5 00 06 00 00 00 
{137} normal block at 0x00A580B8, 12 bytes long.
 Data: <     0      > 00 81 A5 00 F0 30 A5 00 05 00 00 00 
{136} normal block at 0x00A530F0, 12 bytes long.
 Data: <            > B8 80 A5 00 00 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 
Object dump complete.
The program '[5592] linkedlist.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the memory leaks.

Comment: Maybe you can show us code of your destructor and push_back() ?

Comment: The constructor and destructor will be called correctly on the stack. When you create Linkedlist dynamically using `new` and never call the appropriate `delete` anywhere, the destructor will not be called at all. In any case, the problem is probably located somewhere in your implementation of `push_back`, `pop_back` or the destructor, so please post this code as well.

Comment: And while it may have nothing to do with answering your question, I strongly advise you to have a look into `std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr` and so on. It is necessary to learn the basics at first, but it is also equally important to know that in modern C++, manual resource (memory) management (calling new and delete) is not the way of doing things. Also have a look at "RAII".

Comment: I already learned about the unique_ptr and shared_ptr. However, I am not allowed to use these on my exam as the exam is in an older version of C++, not C++11

Comment: Fine with me, I just wanted to make sure. Too much old material out there for C++ beginners. Mentioning the newer stuff for future readers can't hurt :)

Comment: I follow your reasoning :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking for memory leaks before foo goes out of scope, so it doesn't have a chance to call its destructor which in turn probably clears all LL_elements (assumption, since you haven't posted destructor code). Try it like this:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    {
        Linkedlist foo; 
        foo.push_back(3);
        foo.push_back(5);
        foo.push_back(6);
        foo.push_back(7); 
    }
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this helped! 
In the destructor, I called the function pop_back until the size was zero, i think that is a correct way.