# C++ Memory Leak Detection Happening at Wrong Time? (C Arrays)

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I have the following struct in C++ (don't ask why I'm not using `std::vector` instead of C arrays, that's not the question).

```
struct Pizza {
    int w;
    int h;
    char** pizza;
    Pizza(int width, int height) {
        w = width;
        h = height; 
        pizza = new char*[w];
        for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
            pizza[x] = new char[h];
            for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
                pizza[x][y] = '\0';
            }
        }
    }
    ~Pizza() {
        for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
            delete[] pizza[x];
        }
        delete[] pizza;
    }
};
```

I'm using VS2015 and am using:

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC  
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <crtdbg.h>
```

with

```
_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
```

to detect memory leaks and was surprised to see that I had a memory leak with the following code:

```
int main() {
    Pizza p(10,10);
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
}
```

as I was under the impression that `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()` would only detect and display memory leaks after execution (and hence the Pizza destructor would have been called).  As it turns out the following code

```
int main() {
    Pizza *p = new Pizza(10,10);
    delete p;
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
}
```

does not produce a memory leak.  Am I just misunderstanding this quote from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x98tx3cf.aspx):

> you can place a call to _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks before an application exit
>   point to display a memory-leak report when your application exits

or is something else going on here?

I was expecting:

```
int main() {
    Pizza p(10,10);
    // Imaginary p.~Pizza();
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
}
```

to take place, i.e. the destructor is called first, rather than:

```
int main() {
    Pizza p(10,10);
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
    // Imaginary p.~Pizza();
}
```

where the destructor would be called after.

**EDIT:**
Leak Report:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{170} normal block at 0x01364070, 10 bytes long.
 Data: <   (2<FPZd> 0A 14 1E 28 32 3C 46 50 5A 64 
{169} normal block at 0x013642D8, 10 bytes long.
 Data: <   $-6?HQZ> 09 12 1B 24 2D 36 3F 48 51 5A 
{168} normal block at 0x01364380, 10 bytes long.
 Data: <    (08@HP> 08 10 18 20 28 30 38 40 48 50 
{167} normal block at 0x013640E0, 10 bytes long.
 Data: <    #*18?F> 07 0E 15 1C 23 2A 31 38 3F 46 
{166} normal block at 0x01364658, 10 bytes long.
 Data: <     $*06<> 06 0C 12 18 1E 24 2A 30 36 3C 
{165} normal block at 0x013644D0, 10 bytes long.
 Data: <      #(-2> 05 0A 0F 14 19 1E 23 28 2D 32 
{164} normal block at 0x01364348, 10 bytes long.
 Data: <        $(> 04 08 0C 10 14 18 1C 20 24 28 
{163} normal block at 0x013645E8, 10 bytes long.
 Data: <          > 03 06 09 0C 0F 12 15 18 1B 1E 
{162} normal block at 0x013643B8, 10 bytes long.
 Data: <          > 02 04 06 08 0A 0C 0E 10 12 14 
{161} normal block at 0x01364700, 10 bytes long.
 Data: <          > 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 
{160} normal block at 0x0135DCA8, 40 bytes long.
 Data: < G6  C6  E6 HC6 > 00 47 36 01 B8 43 36 01 E8 45 36 01 48 43 36 01 
Object dump complete.
```

Here I used `(x+1)*(y+1)` to fill the values.

Comment: Can you show the leak report?  It should be showing line numbers where the allocation occurred for each block that leaked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Memory leaks despite destructor call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30325372/memory-leaks-despite-destructor-call)

Comment: Not related to your issue, but you have a bug in `y < w`. It should read `y < h`.

Comment: Why would the framework put _imaginary_ anything? Isn't the point - calculating the actual memory allocations, rather that imagining various scenarios?

Comment: ***is there any particular reason why the memory dump occurs before the execution finishes rather than after exiting main and before the process is handed back to the OS?*** Because the leak report is generated when  you tell it to happen (when you call `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();`)

Comment: In`int main() {Pizza p(10,10);  _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();}`, `p` will be destructed AFTER `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()` returns - i.e. as it passes out of scope from `main()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the program exits, you obviously don't have any memory leaks, as all memory is handed back to the OS. The easiest way to get the destructor called is simply to add another scope:

```
int main() {
    {
         Pizza p(10,10);
    }
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
}
```

Comment: Or OP could simply call `_CrtSetDbgFlag ( _CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF );` at the beginning of his application.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius, I think, this warrants a separate answer.

Comment: @SergeyA Point taken :)

Comment: @Nick _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks() is a function (or something that calls a function), so you get the leak dump when you call it. This is intentional, so you can place it at places of interest in your code, not just at the end of main().

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the article, you [linked in the question](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x98tx3cf.aspx):

> If your application has multiple exits, you do not need to manually place a call to _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks at every exit point. A call to `_CrtSetDbgFlag` at the beginning of your application will cause an automatic call to `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks` at each exit point. You must set the two bit fields shown here: `_CrtSetDbgFlag (_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);`.

So, you could call it, as follows:

```
int main ()
    {
    _CrtSetDbgFlag (_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
    // Your actual code
    }
```